# useSelector (from Redux +React) returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, useselector

I am using React + TypeScript for development and using Redux for centralised state management - to store the current user logged in.

[Here is the userReducer:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moPOK.png)

[Here is the store:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeMqu.png)

[Here is the snippet of code inside my React component, where I try to access the user state:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKPHS.png)

I'm not sure why `useSelector` returned undefined since I have defined an initialState in the `userReducer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you defined the root state as `{user}`.  In other words, the `userReducer`'s data is attached to the root state as `state.user`.

So, your selector needs to be `state => state.user`.

You also have a problem in your store file. You've created *another* reducer function with `const rootReducer = combineReducers({userReducer})`, and then inferred the `RootState` type from that.

That is wrong in two ways:

- That reducer function is *not* being used at all!  `configureStore` already made its own root reducer function from the definition you provided and is using that
- Your `RootState` type is wrong, because it's being inferred from the wrong function

That's why you're not even getting a TS error here.

Instead, you need to delete the `combineReducers` line, and then do:

```
type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

per our TS usage docs:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types

Comment: Thanks for your swift answer! I ended up changing `user: userReducer` in store.ts to `userReducer: userReducer` and that worked. Your comment helped a bunch, thanks <3

Comment: Note that we generally recommend _against_ using the word "reducer" as part of a state slice key name: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#name-state-slices-based-on-the-stored-data .  In other words, you _should_ have `state.user`, not `state.userReducer` .